# Hadoop LZO & SnappyCodec error in Hadoop and Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, lzo, snappy

I am using Ubuntu-12.04,Hadoop-1.0.2,Hive-0.10.0
while reading data about 1 million records from hive I got error below for query

```
select * from raw_pos limit 10000;
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

so I installed Snappy for Hadoop in $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder,which produces files libsnappy.a, libsnappy.la,libsnappy.so,libsnappy.so.1,libsnappy.so.1.1.4

also add hadoop-lzo-0.4.3.jar in $HADOOP_HOME/lib/ & make changes in cor-site.xml,mapred-site.xml as follow

Core-site.xml:-

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop_temp/</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>io.compression.codecs</name>
<value>
  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
</value>
```

mapred-site.xml :-

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54311</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

but when I started hive & do `show databases`, gives error:-

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Cannot create an instance of InputFormat class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat as specified in mapredWork!
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your core-site.xml to this and see if it helps :

```
<property>
<name>io.compression.codecs</name>
<value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
<value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```